# Google Analytics API v3 /Fatal error:Class 'Google_Service' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics-api, xampp

初心者です。
ローカル環境の Wordpress で簡単な自作のプラグインを作って、
そこに GoogleAnalytics の値を表示しようとしていのですが、うまくいきません。

> Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\lansub\wp-content\plugins\practice\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php on line 32

というエラーが出ます。

```
require_once '\src\Google\Client.php';
require_once '\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php';

// サービスアカウント名（メールアドレス）
$service_account_name = 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
// P12キーファイルのパス
$key_file_location = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\lansub\wp-content\plugins\practice\xxxxxx.p12';
// アナリティクスのビューID 例)'ga:1234567'
$analytics_view_id = 'ga:xxxxxxx';

session_start();

if ( !strlen($service_account_name)
    || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
}

$client = new Google_Client();

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

// アナリティクスクライアントを生成
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

try {
    // リアルタイムデータを取得する
    $results = $analytics->data_realtime->get(
            $analytics_view_id, // アナリティクスのビューID(アナリティクス設定 -> ビュー -> ビュー設定から確認)
            'rt:activeUsers'  // リアルタイムアクティブユーザー数を取得
    );

    // 取得結果からリアルタイムアクティブユーザ数を取り出す
    $totals = $results->getTotalsForAllResults();
    // activeUsers:ユーザ数 の配列に加工
    $array = array("activeUsers" => $totals["rt:activeUsers"]);

    // JSONに変換して表示
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
     echo json_encode($array);

} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Analytics.php を見ても意味が分かりませんでした。
解決の糸口が何かないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `\src\Google\autoload.php` でオートローダが使えるはずなので試してみてください. require するだけで大丈夫です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーの文言の通り、`/src/Google/Service.php` を include してみてください.

```
require_once '\src\Google\Client.php';
require_once '\src\Google\Service.php';
require_once '\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php';
```

そしてこうした煩わしさから解放されるため、autoload.php も用意されています.

```
require_once '\src\Google\autoload.php';
```

参考：[PHP クラスのオートローディング](http://php.net/manual/ja/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーはなくなりました。しかし
結果が何も表示されず、コンソールエラーが出ています。
`GET http://localhost/lansub/wp-admin/tools.php?page=practice-plugin-top-level net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
VM294 tools.php?page=practice-plugin-top-level:1 `

VM294 tools.php?page=practice-plugin-top-level:1 をクリックすると以下のコードが出ます。

Comment: `<script>
addLoadEvent = function(func){if(typeof jQuery!="undefined")jQuery(document).ready(func);else if(typeof wpOnload!='function'){wpOnload=func;}else{var oldonload=wpOnload;wpOnload=function(){oldonload();func();}}};
var ajaxurl = '/lansub/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
 pagenow = 'tools_page_practice-plugin-top-level',
 typenow = '',
 adminpage = 'tools_page_practice-plugin-top-level',
 thousandsSeparator = ',',
 decimalPoint = '.',
 isRtl = 0;
</script>`
何かわかることはあるでしょうか？

Comment: また単純なプラグインのecho文も消えてしまっています。

Comment: ローカルで動かしていることもうまくいかない原因になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: ローカルで動かしているのであれば、環境は XAMPP でしょうか？

Comment: はいxamppです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ん、回答のチェックがついていますが、問題は解決されましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。サーバーにあげてテストしたら一応動きました。
ローカルでのテストが無理だったようで

Comment: ご協力ありがとうございます。なんとか運用できそうです。

Answer (score 0):

You have to include these lines in Analytics.php file to include all other files.

```
define('APP_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(APP_PATH . "/../Service.php");
require_once(APP_PATH . "/../Model.php");
require_once(APP_PATH . "/../Collection.php");
require_once(APP_PATH . "/../Config.php");
require_once 'Resource.php';`
```

Its works for me.